# If the "try" option in ubuntu's installer works alright would the install be ok as well

Tags: system-installation, laptop, acer

I've recently been interested in installing ubuntu instead of my "pre-installed" windows 10, on my acer A315-21 laptop (I replaced my hard drive and installed windows 10 on it but the laptop came with windows 10 in the first place.) I have tried out ubuntu with the install usb and for the most part it works well (Aside from the screen flickering black once in a while which, correct me if i'm wrong might be fixed with a driver update) My question is, would there be any problem if I installed Ubuntu, aside from the aforementioned screen issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it would be alright. I would suggest dual-booting (having both Windows and Ubuntu installed) just in case something doesn't work or you don't like the Ubuntu way for solving it. For instance, from my personal experience, LibreOffice is not always 100% compatible with Microsoft Office, and for gaming, sometimes WINE doesn't work well enough.

Comment: If Try Ubuntu is working well, most installer issues are from Windows having odd install, like having dynamic instead of basic partition/s or if an Intel machine with SSD and HHD and using RST instead of ACHI(BIOS/UEFI setting).  Both can be changed, but need to adjust Windows first or Windows gives sissy fit.

Comment: Yes, RST feature using Intel Optane SSD is unfortunately not yet supported in Ubuntu... I don't have one myself so I can't tinker around with it, but this might be a good place to start: https://www.codenotary.com/blog/ubuntu-how-to-use-intel-optane-memory-for-ssd-caching/

Comment: I forgot to mention this but I have my hdd under legacy boot because it's not compatible with uefi,would that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. You need to convert the partitioning scheme from MBR to GPT in order to make it compatible with UEFI. https://serverfault.com/questions/963178/how-do-i-convert-my-linux-disk-from-mbr-to-gpt-with-uefi

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Why would I need the usb to be compatible with uefi if the hard drive is on legacy?

Comment: Can install Ubuntu in legacy mode on MBR.  Just need to check that installer USB is set for Legacy.  If on legacy/MBR can only have four partitions on drive, one can be logical instead primary.